# Ответ 426, сайт требует протокол HTTP/2.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, requests

Код 426. Нужно обновить протокол. Кто решал такую проблему?

```
r = requests.get('https://maxmaster.ru/')
print(r)


result code [426]
```

Comment: Ваш вопрос со ссылкой похож на спам. Коли это не так - поясните при чём тут ссылка и что за донор, внеся правку в вопрос.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб get запрос на сайт, ответ код 426.

Comment: В Google Colab ответ `<Response [200]>`. Может у вас какие-то древние версии библиотек?

Comment: @CrazyElf вроде все ок.

Comment: Либо вы всё же неточно указываете URL по которому обращаетесь. Могу предположить, что вы обращаетесь к какому-то содержимому, где сайт хочет, чтобы вы были залогинены, а для этого предлагает вам перейти с http протокола на https для безопасности. Но это явно не главная страница - там всё ок вроде.

Comment: Покажите что выдаёт `print(r.headers)` и `print(r.request.headers)`

Comment: тоже 426, даже с user-agent в headers... r.headers: 
{'Date': 'Thu, 18 Mar 2021 15:24:33 GMT', 'Content-Length': '0', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Server': 'ua1', 'X-Edge-IP': '45.137.155.140', 'X-Edge-Location': 'ua1'}   
r.request.headers: 
{'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/426

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Библиотека `requests` не умеет работать с `2.0`.

Погуглил библиотеки, что умеют с `2.0` и нашлось `hyper` (`pip install hyper`)

Пример:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from hyper import HTTPConnection

conn = HTTPConnection('maxmaster.ru:443')
conn.request('GET', '/')
resp = conn.get_response()
print(resp.status)
# 200

root = BeautifulSoup(resp.read(), 'html.parser')
print(root.select_one('head > title').text)
# MAXMASTER - интернет-магазин электроинструмента, ...
```